# Migrating Java application from Jboss eap-6.3 to Wildfly 9

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to transfer application that runs on a server Jboss eap-6.3 on the server Wildfly 9.

*The standalone log*

```
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00.jar\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"calculator-ws-1.00.00.jar\" of deployment \"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaAllMember",
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00\".WServicesServerDAOImpl.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00\".WServicesServerDAOImpl]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00\".WServicesServerDAOImpl.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00\".WServicesServerDAOImpl]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".WeldStartService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00.jar\".jndiDependencyService]",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00.jar\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".deploymentCompleteService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00.jar\".deploymentCompleteService]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00\".WServicesServerDAOImpl.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00\".WServicesServerDAOImpl]",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00.jar\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00.ear\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00.jar\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00\".WServicesServerDAOImpl.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"calculator-jee-1.00.00\".\"calculator-ws-1.00.00\".WServicesServerDAOImpl]"
    ]
}
```

Can somebody help me? I am newbie to the JBoss and Wildfly environment

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your application requires the org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaAllMember class which is included into the latest xmlschema-core.
You can add a dependency to your application.
Good luck.